# Question on Contractions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n ;  \|x\| \le 1  \}$ and $f: S \to S$ be a contraction. Determine one can have $f(S) = S$.

I really need some help with this question. In advance I wanted to give all the necessary definitions needed for this question.

**Definition**:

1. Let $(X, P)$, $(Y, P')$ be metric spaces and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a function. Let $M \in \mathbb{R}$ with $M > 0$. We say that $f$ satisfies a **Lipschitz  condition** with Lipschitz constant $M$ if $\forall x, y \in X: P'(f(x), f(y)) \le M P(x,y)$
2. Let $(X, P)$, $(Y, P)$ be metric spaces and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a function. We say that $f$ is a **contraction** (mapping) if $f$ satisfies the  **Lipschitz  condition** on $X$ with some Lipschitz constant $M \in (0,1)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "Determine one can have $f(S) = S$"?

Comment: @martini as I have defined f is a function such that it maps S to S and we have defined what S is (i.e: norm less than or equal 1). Is it possible to have such mapping ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\xi \in S$ by the fixed point of $f$ which exists by the Banach fixed point theorem. Now the function $d \colon S \to \mathbb R$, $x \mapsto \|x-\xi\|$ attains its maximum on $S$, as $S$ is compact. Let $\eta \in S$ such that $d(\eta) \ge d(x)$ for all $x \in S$. Let $q \in [0,1)$ by a Lipschitz constant for $f$, then for all $x \in S$:
$$
  d(f(x)) = \|f(x) - \xi\| = \|f(x) - f(\xi)\| \le q \|x-\xi\| = qd(x) \le qd(\eta) < d(\eta).
$$
Hence $f(x) \ne \eta$ and $f$ isn't onto.

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $g:S\times S\longrightarrow [0,+\infty)$ defined by
$$
g:(x,y)\longmapsto \|f(x)-f(y)\|.
$$
Since $g$ is continuous and $S\times S$ is compact, it attains its sup, which is the diameter of $f(S)$:
$$
\mbox{diameter} \;f(S)=\sup g=\max g=\|f(x_0)-f(y_0)\|<\|x_0-y_0\|\leq 2=\mbox{diameter} \;S.
$$
Since they don't have the same diameter, the sets $S$ and $f(S)$ can't be equal.